# Multiple FileUploadListener on one View

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have 2 fileupload forms in one view with different methods called. The problem is, that the file wizzard is opened twice, since both listener are called.
Here a snipped of my code

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileBean.handleFileUpload1}" 
            auto="true"/>
</h:form>
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileBean.handleFileUpload2}" 
            auto="true"/>
</h:form>
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try to add id to your forms ?!?

Comment: Hi @yagami. Can you explain what you mean with "forms"?

Comment: when you work with `fileUpload ` every one is in a dialog, i was a little bit disrubted by your forms is it the case in your project (does every `fileUpload` belong to a dialog) ?!?

Comment: No. i dont have the filupload forms in dialogs.